# Can't create conda environment with tensorflow and pytorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, conda

I am trying to create a conda environment that contains both tensorflow and pytorch. As a minimal example, I am running

`conda env create -n test -f test-env.yaml`

using the following `test-env.yaml` file:

```
channels:
- conda-forge
- defaults
- pyviz

dependencies:
- python>=3.7,<3.8
- tensorflow>=2.0.0,<2.4.0
- pytorch>=1.0.0,<2.0.0
name: my_environment
```

I get the following long error complaining about conflicts:

```
$ conda env create -n test -f test-env.yaml
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package _libgcc_mutex conflicts for:
pytorch[version='>=1.0.0,<2.0.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build='conda_forge|main|main']
python[version='>=3.7,<3.8'] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build='conda_forge|main']

Package python conflicts for:
tensorflow[version='>=2.0.0,<2.4.0'] -> python[version='2.7.*|3.6.*|3.7.*|3.8.*']
python[version='>=3.7,<3.8']
tensorflow[version='>=2.0.0,<2.4.0'] -> tensorboard[version='>=2.3.0'] -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3|>=3.2|>=3.5|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']
pytorch[version='>=1.0.0,<2.0.0'] -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
pytorch[version='>=1.0.0,<2.0.0'] -> cffi -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|3.6.12|3.6.12|3.7.9|3.6.9|3.6.9|3.6.9|3.6.9|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|3.4.*|3.9.*|>=3.5|3.8.*|3.7.*|>=3.7|>=3.6,<3.7|>=3',build='1_73_pypy|3_73_pypy|4_73_pypy|5_73_pypy|2_73_pypy|0_73_pypy']

Package setuptools conflicts for:
tensorflow[version='>=2.0.0,<2.4.0'] -> tensorboard[version='>=2.3.0'] -> setuptools[version='>=41.0.0|>=41.4']
python[version='>=3.7,<3.8'] -> pip -> setuptools

Package numpy conflicts for:
tensorflow[version='>=2.0.0,<2.4.0'] -> tensorboard[version='>=2.3.0'] -> numpy[version='>=1.12.0|>=1.16|>=1.16.6,<2.0a0|>=1.16.1']
pytorch[version='>=1.0.0,<2.0.0'] -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0|>=1.16.6,<2.0a0|>=1.19.5,<2.0a0|>=1.19.4,<2.0a0|>=1.14.6,<2.0a0']

Package cudatoolkit conflicts for:
pytorch[version='>=1.0.0,<2.0.0'] -> cudnn[version='>=7.6,<8.0a0'] -> cudatoolkit[version='11.0|11.0.*|>=10.0,<10.1|>=10.1,<10.2|>=9.0,<9.1|>=9.2,<9.3|>=10.2,<10.3|11.2|11.2.*|11.1|11.1.*|9.0.*|8.0.*']
pytorch[version='>=1.0.0,<2.0.0'] -> cudatoolkit[version='10.0.*|10.0|10.0.*|10.1|10.1.*|10.2|10.2.*|9.2|9.2.*|>=10.1.243,<10.2.0a0|>=9.2,<9.3.0a0|>=10.0.130,<10.1.0a0|9.2.*|>=9.0,<9.1.0a0|>=8.0,<8.1.0a0']

Package _openmp_mutex conflicts for:
pytorch[version='>=1.0.0,<2.0.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
pytorch[version='>=1.0.0,<2.0.0'] -> mkl[version='>=2020.4,<2021.0a0'] -> _openmp_mutex=[build=*_llvm]The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.17=0
  - pytorch[version='>=1.0.0,<2.0.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17,<3.0.a0']
  - pytorch[version='>=1.0.0,<2.0.0'] -> magma[version='>=2.5.4,<2.5.5.0a0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

Your installed version is: 2.17

Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.
```

If I set `channel_priority` to flexible instead of strict, it does work. However, I would really like this to work with strict channel priority if possible. Is there any way to make it work?

Here is the output of conda info:

```
$ conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : /home/kgullikson/miniconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/kgullikson/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/kgullikson/.condarc
          conda version : 4.9.2
    conda-build version : 3.20.3
         python version : 3.6.11.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=11.2=0
                          __glibc=2.17=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /home/kgullikson/miniconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/pyviz/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/pyviz/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/kgullikson/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/kgullikson/noarch
          package cache : /home/kgullikson/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /home/kgullikson/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/kgullikson/miniconda3/envs
                          /home/kgullikson/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.25.1 CPython/3.6.11 Linux/3.10.0-1160.11.1.el7.x86_64 centos/7.6.1810 glibc/2.17
                UID:GID : 207402735:207400513
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

And my `.condarc`:

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - pyviz
  - defaults
  - kgullikson
conda-build:
  root-dir: ~/conda-builds
  skip_existing: true
pip_interop_enabled: false
channel_priority: strict
```

## UPDATE:

Reading more closely through the documentation on conda, it seems like this is actually the expected behavior of strict channel priority.
https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html

Namely:

> With strict channel priority, packages in lower
> priority channels are not considered if a package with the same name
> appears in a higher priority channel

So the problem here is that there are in fact tensorflow packages in conda-forge, just none that satisfy my requirement of using tensorflow 2. Given that they are pushing people to use strict and that they plan to make it the default in conda 5, that seems problematic...

Comment: I can confirm the behavior, including the fact that toggling to `channel_priority: flexible` gets it working. I'm a bit baffled why it doesn't work - the only thing that stands out is that **conda-forge** channel doesn't have `tensorflow>=2`, but really not sure why it can't handle just using the **defaults** version. I'd file a bug report on [the Conda repo](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues). Otherwise, maybe you can expand on why you don't want the flexible solve.

Comment: Only other thought is that perhaps the `strict` solve is precluding certain dependencies that are required for using the `tensorflow>=2` from the **defaults** channel. It also sucks that the conflict reporting is soooo useless, but that has been a problem since they added it.

Comment: I just updated. It actually seems to be the expected behavior for strict channel priority, even though it is pretty confusing